# Open excel file from process.start - filename breaking

Tags: c#, excel, windows-forms-designer

My code is:

```
string Xlsx_path = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("EXCEL.exe", "\"" + Xlsx_path + "/textexcel.xlsx" + "\"");
```

but the result is

> 'C:\Program Files (x86)\BEB5C000' file not executable'

I guess that

> 'textexcel.xlsx' value change to 'BEB5C000'

but I cannot find the reason.

Comment: What is the datatype and value of `Xlsx_path`?

Comment: What is the full path of your excel file with name ? What value is getting passed in Xlsx_path ? Can you open your excel file from same file path that is getting passed as argument for Process class ?

Comment: The machine has been compromised by malware.  It did not manage to get started, but you can't be sure what else it messed with.  Re-imaging the machine is certainly best.

Comment: I incorporated some code from the comments and reformulated some aspects of the question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
string Xlsx_path = @"D:\Test"; // your file path
string fileName = "textexcel.xlsx";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path.Combine(Xlsx_path, fileName));
```